# Conditionally apply ng-class within Angular Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm fairly new to Angular, I am attempting to wrap a radio input:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="animal" name="fun" value="dog" radio />
<input type="radio" ng-model="animal" name="fun" value="cat" radio />
```

And conditionally apply a class within a directive to the **wrapping element** based on if the value of the radio equals the model (the radio button is selected)

http://jsfiddle.net/TSM_mac/HB7LU/141/

```
.directive('radio', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.wrap('<div class="radio-wrap" ng-class="checked:attrs.value==attrs.ngModel}"></div>');
        }
    }  
})
```

Ive considered using the template property, and then wrapping the element with the template. I have also considered using $compile.

Any advice is appreciated

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what your question is and what problems you are experiencing.

Comment: The problem I am experiencing is that attrs.value==attrs.ngModel is not evaluated, thus the "checked" class is not applied (or not applied) to the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `ng-class="checked:attrs.value==attrs.ngModel}"` should be `ng-class="{checked:attrs.value==attrs.ngModel}"`

Second, your expression makes no sense. `ng-class` is evaluated on your view during the digest cycle. It is not evaluated in your directive during your `link` function call. Because of this, when ng-class is evaluated, there will be no `attrs` variable and, of course, it will evaluate to false.

Comment: @GuillaumeMassé First, please don't confuse direct language with lack of manners. Second, the issue you linked is unrelated to this question. The asker was attempting to access values outside of scope inside of an angular expression, which literally doesn't make sense. The issue that you linked is a feature suggestion that involves merging two ng-class expressions.